# Group or select list Items with specific time range using C#

Tags: c#

I have list with test name and processed date. I want test names with specific time limit and want to ignore items which are listed in that limit. Please find the below example for reference .

Example :

```
Name LoggedDate

T1   29/9/2018 10:10:03:014  
T1   29/9/2018 10:10:03:120  
T1   29/9/2018 10:10:03:150  
T1   29/9/2018 10:10:04:012  
T1   29/9/2018 10:11:04:014  
T1   29/9/2018 10:11:04:220  
T1   29/9/2018 10:11:04:014  
T1   29/9/2018 10:11:05:014
```

Result :

```
T1   29/9/2018 10:10:03:00    
T1   29/9/2018 10:11:04:00 
T1   29/9/2018 10:11:05:00
```

I need only 2 records from list and ignore other records which are processed in that time range (1 minute range). please help.

-
Sachin

Comment: Hi @sachin, shouldn't `T1 29/9/2018 10:11:05:00` be on the result list as well? If not, why not?

Comment: Please show what you tried so far, and what the actual result was.

Comment: Google for a linq tutorial.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin : Yes your right!! I forgot to mentioned it.

Comment: @BrianMinton :I tried this but no proper results :( var result= testList.GroupBy(s => s.LoggedDate.Ticks / (1 * TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute)).Select(s => new { testList = s.ToList() });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) for that.
With LINQ we can do numerous operations on `Collections`.
What you need in your example would be something like:

```
var filteredList = items

        // Group the itens on the list by its Name, Date, hour and Minute, so you are basically ignoring the seconds
        .GroupBy(g => g.Name + " " + g.LoggedDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + g.LoggedDate.Hour + g.LoggedDate.Minute)

        // Get the first one of each group
        .Select(o => o.First())

        // Turn into a list
        .ToList();
```

Checkout the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rr4osX

Comment: Thanks for answer but It wont work for different test set with same time frame. Like T2 is also in same time format then it wont consider T2 it consider only T1 set first items. I tried this. ...It should work for different Test (T1 ,T2 ,T3.....) sets and with different time stamps (one minute difference).                                                                                     Sample : https://dotnetfiddle.net/hTlWE5

Comment: Just add the `Name` on the group key as well. I updated my answer.

Comment: @sachin did it work for you? If so, could you please check my answer as accepted?

Comment: Yessss!!.. It works perfectly as expected... Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not clear as @Menighin ask, why not T1 29/9/2018 10:11:05:00 be on the result list and why you want just two, here is something that you are asking for. Compare two successive data and check their time difference in minute.

```
List<TestClass> items = new List<TestClass>
        {
            new TestClass
            {
                Name = "T1",
                LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 9,29 , 10, 10, 03, 014)
            },
            new TestClass
            {
                Name = "T1",
                LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 9, 29, 10, 10, 03, 120)
            },
            new TestClass
            {
                Name = "T1",
                LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 9, 29, 10, 10, 04, 012)
            },
            new TestClass
            {
                Name = "T1",
                LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 9, 29, 11, 10, 04, 014)
            },
            new TestClass
            {
                Name = "T1",
                LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 9, 29, 11, 10, 04, 220)
            },
            new TestClass
            {
                Name = "T1",
                LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 9, 29, 11, 10, 04, 014)
            },
            new TestClass
            {
                Name = "T1",
                LoggedDate = new DateTime(29, 9, 29, 10, 11, 05, 014)
            }

        };

       List<TestClass> resultList = new List<TestClass>();
       for (int i = 0; i < items.Count-1; i++)
        {

                if (items[i].LoggedDate.Minute - items[i + 1].LoggedDate.Minute == -1)
                {
                    resultList.Add(items[i]);
                    resultList.Add(items[i + 1]);
                    break;
                }             
        }
```

*resultList* is what exactly you looking for. Be sure your data is in ascending order before you compare.

Comment: Thanks for reply !!. As i mentioned above I want 1 minute result set from list .           T1   29/9/2018 10:10:03:00    
T1   29/9/2018 10:11:04:00                                                                                           T1   29/9/2018 10:11:05:00

Comment: Then please rewrite your sample answer and make sure you provide correct details when you asking a question.Your sample result just have there is only two!!!! @sachin

Comment: Updated my question. Thanks